# prevent directory access

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have this current directory structure

```
myproject
  --> application
  --> assets
  --> data
  --> scripts
  --> styles
  --> system
  --> .htaccess
  --> favicon.ico
  --> index.php
```

I store my users uploaded images, videos on the **data** directory, and it has this structure:

```
data
  --> 5
      --> thumbs
      --> user_images
  --> 6
      --> thumbs
      --> user_images
  --> index.html
```

I placed **index.html** to prevent directory access. I can do this to all the data subdirectories to have the same effect, however is there a way to have this handled by .htaccess? I tried `Deny from all` rule in the .htaccess but it also won't allow me to use my images in my system. All I want to achieve is to prevent directory access (when direct access from URL) from my data directory. How is that?

Comment: Take a look at the "Options" directive. It allows to grant or refuse directory listings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `.htaccess`, add the following line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

See [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) for further details.

Comment: Should I create a new .htaccess under the `data` directory?

Comment: @grrr: I thought you already had that, and tried to put your `Deny` rule there. But yes, this should go into `data/.htaccess`, existing or newly created.